# Add pre-filled resizable text boxes (forms.Textarea) to the django form

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I need to create a form, where text-boxes would be resizable (so `Textarea` widget has to be used) and pre-filled. I tried to pre-fill them through `.initial` and `value` attribute.

**Problem:**

- If `Textarea` widget is used: text boxes are resizable but **no value** is shown

```
forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows": 1, "cols": 50, "value":column_data})
self.fields[f'inserted_value_{column_name}'].initial=column_data
```

- If `TextInput` widget is used: text boxes are **not resizable** but value is shown

```
forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"rows": 1, "cols": 50, "value":column_data})
```

There amount of form elements (always the same Text-box) is going to be dynamic, so they are created in `def __init__` and should also get their value there. Theoretically value attribute should work, but it returns me empty text-boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have more code examples...
`textarea` does not have a "value" attribute, text is inserted directly into the `<textarea>here</textarea>` tag by default. Perhaps you would better define the tag like this

```
<textarea rows="1", cols="50">{{column_data}}</textarea>
```

note "column_data" will need to be passed in the context of the template

Comment: Is there a way to pre-fill textarea form element from forms.py (in django) instead of adding value from the template?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37380627/how-do-you-add-default-value-to-django-form-textarea Maybe this will help you, but if you need dynamic data, then I don’t know any other way as I described